# JOSM popup(window) need to hide while converting shape file to osm.pbf

Tags: c#, wpf

we are now using JOSM to convert shape files to osm.pbf in wpf c# application as while converting,JOSM window is coming to save as osm.pbf so my reuirement is to get it done backend only without showing the popup and also save as option also should not give it to user.

am finding other way to generate the pbf file from shape files as am new to this Geo domain development.